# ListView Issue: Only First Element Appears, Subsequent Elements Not Displayed

Tags: android, kotlin, listview

I'm having issues with the listView, which only loads the first element. The subsequent elements added when pressing the buttonAddNewLoad button are not being displayed.

In onViewCreated I define an adapter called "adapter" and then add it to  binding.listAppList.adapter = adapter

```
class DHouseFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentDwellingsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private val load = Loads ()
    val loadApplianceList: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
        
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentDBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // some code

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(binding.root.context, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, loadApplianceList) // Use string adapter
        binding.listAppList.adapter = adapter

   
        binding.buttonAddNewLoad.setOnClickListener{
           
            load.addLoad(loadTypeSelected, quantity.toInt(), power.toFloat(), description)
            loadApplianceList.add("Quantity - $quantity")

            adapter.add("$Quantity - $quantity") 
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                  
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share the XML layout for the Fragment as well. Is the ListView's height large enough to fit more than one item?

Comment: It's redundant to call `add` both on your backing list and through the adapter. Current code is adding two items to the list each time the button is clicked.